# Using $onChanges hook on Isolate Scope One Way Binding in directives

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have the following directive :

```
// expose directive
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: linkFn,
            scope: {
                treeModel: "<"
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                var vm = this;
            },
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
```

What I want to do is to watch changes on `treeModel`, so in my link function I did as following :

```
function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('treeModel', function(value){
        if(value instanceof Array){
            scope.tree.jstree(true).settings.core.data = value;
            scope.tree.jstree(true).refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

Which works in this case (this code gets executed twice the first time `value` is undefined, but in the second time `value` is an array of objects), but I want to implement the `$onChanges` hook, since I'm planning to migrate my application to Angular 2, so  I did as following :

```
// expose directive
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: linkFn,
            scope: {
                treeModel: "<"
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.$onChanges = function (changes) {
                    if($scope.treeModel instanceof Array){
                        $scope.tree.jstree(true).settings.core.data = $scope.treeModel;
                        $scope.tree.jstree(true).refresh();
                    }

                };
            },
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
```

And then I removed the `scope.$watch` code from my link function.

When I tried this, it doesn't work and `vm.$onChanges` get triggered only once where value is undefined and never gets triggered the second time as with the `scope.$watch`, and the  `changes` parameter is always undefined when it should be an object where keys are bindings names that changes.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you please post a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use $doCheck, as $onChanges does only watch for reference changes, it does not deep watch:

[See this article, which describes the replacement of a watcher with $doCheck](http://www.codelord.net/2016/12/20/replacing-angulars-deep-watches-with-the-%24docheck-lifecycle-hook/)

> While it’s possible to use $onChanges for being notified about changes to references on bindings, there’s no easy way to do it for mutations without $scope.$watch